# Python whois fails after converting to an exe

Tags: python, whois

I am new to python, just started working with it a few weeks ago and as a project I wrote a program to assist agents in my department with host, whois and mx lookups.

Running the program as a .py everything works as intended. But when I convert the .py to an exe using auto_py_to_exe or pyinstaller the host and mx features work but the whois portion fails with the following error:

The DNS query name does not exist:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI109402\whois\data\public_suffix_list.dat'

I am at a loss after searching on my own for answers. I assume I am missing something simple. Any help would be awesome.

My imports:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import dns.resolver
import socket
import whois
import pywhois
```

The code in question:

```
def whois_lookup():
    # Get Whois data
    try:
        hostName = values["-getHost-"]
        w = whois.whois(hostName)
        tld = hostName.split(".")[-1]
        nameservers = dns.resolver.query(hostName, "NS")
        if tld == "ca":
            window["-textbox-"].print("Registrar: ", w.registrar, "\nExpiration Date: ", w.expiration_date, "\n",)
            window["-textbox-"].print("Name Servers: ")
            for data in nameservers:
                window["-textbox-"].print(data)
        else: # same for now but .ca and the other tld's are different in how they display their data.
            window["-textbox-"].print("Registrar: ", w.registrar, "\nExpiration Date: ", w.expiration_date, "\n",)
            window["-textbox-"].print("Name Servers: ")
            for data in nameservers:
                window["-textbox-"].print(data)
    except Exception as err:
        window["-textbox-"].print("The DNS query name does not exist: ", err)
    return()
```

Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/shawn71/pythonProjects)

autopy output if needed

```
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.11.0
Building directory: C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpx4w5o9ae
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --exclude-module "_bootlocale"  "C:/Users/shawn/Documents/GitHub/pythonProjects/dnsQuery.py"
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --exclude-module _bootlocale C:/Users/shawn/Documents/GitHub/pythonProjects/dnsQuery.py --distpath C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpx4w5o9ae\application --workpath C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpx4w5o9ae\build --specpath C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpx4w5o9ae

48597 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.7
48612 INFO: Python: 3.8.12 (conda)
48632 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
48644 INFO: wrote C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpx4w5o9ae\dnsQuery.spec
48665 INFO: UPX is not available.
48681 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\shawn\\Documents\\GitHub\\pythonProjects']
49145 INFO: checking Analysis
49147 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
49152 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
49165 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
49213 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
53111 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
53116 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib'
57286 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
57644 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
57685 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\shawn\miniconda3\envs\devops\python.exe
58179 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\shawn\Documents\GitHub\pythonProjects\dnsQuery.py
59293 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
59297 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
61684 INFO: Processing module hooks...
61698 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-dns.rdata.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
65332 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
65705 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
65711 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
65726 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
65731 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
65743 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
65877 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
65890 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
65979 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
65990 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
66000 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
66511 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
66843 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
66850 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
66873 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68043 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68056 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68062 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68172 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68393 INFO: checking Tree
68398 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
68405 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
68595 INFO: checking Tree
68600 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
68607 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
68759 INFO: checking Tree
68763 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
68770 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
68804 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-Crypto.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
68833 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68929 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
69058 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
69083 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
69098 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
69114 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
69127 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
69140 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
69174 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
69834 INFO: Looking for eggs
69838 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\shawn\miniconda3\envs\devops\python38.dll
69847 INFO: Found binding redirects: 
[]
69866 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpx4w5o9ae\build\dnsQuery\warn-dnsQuery.txt
70027 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpx4w5o9ae\build\dnsQuery\xref-dnsQuery.html
70117 INFO: checking PYZ
70126 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
70136 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpx4w5o9ae\build\dnsQuery\PYZ-00.pyz
71585 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpx4w5o9ae\build\dnsQuery\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
71638 INFO: checking PKG
71643 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
71657 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) dnsQuery.pkg
77419 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) dnsQuery.pkg completed successfully.
77497 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\shawn\miniconda3\envs\devops\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
77502 INFO: checking EXE
77519 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
77524 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
77536 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpx4w5o9ae\application\dnsQuery.exe
77652 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
77662 INFO: Copying icons from ['C:\\Users\\shawn\\miniconda3\\envs\\devops\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\images\\icon-windowed.ico']
77768 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
77776 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
77786 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
77796 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
77818 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 38188 bytes
77833 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
77839 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
77845 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
77858 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
77867 INFO: Emedding manifest in EXE
77881 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpx4w5o9ae\application\dnsQuery.exe
77979 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
77995 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
84755 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.

Moving project to: C:\Users\shawn\Desktop
Complete.
```

Answer (score 2):

The `whois` module includes a data file, `data/public_suffix_list.dat`.  You'll need to add that to your `pyinstaller` directive file as an external data item.  They should have just made that a Python module.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Do you happen to know where that might be loaded form off hand? That temp dir does not exist.

Comment: I found and added the file from C:/Users/shawn/miniconda3/pkgs/python-whois-0.7.2-py_0/site-packages/whois/data/public_suffix_list.dat but I still get the same error.

Comment: You have to specify the right destination; it has to go in `whois/data`.  I've submitted a pull request for this, if you're feeling adventuresome, you can use my fork from https://github.com/timrprobocom/whois.git.

Comment: Perfect thanks so much.  I have it working as "one dir". I'll continue to see how to get it working as "one file".

Answer (score 0):

As the conversation between the poster Tim Robbins and the OP left a bit unattended. I was able to get this to work as well as ONEFILE by modifying the generated pyinstaller spec file.

For anyone else who needs to solve this (or similar). I suggest you generate the spec file (refer to PyInstaller docs but it's either `pyi-makespec --onefile pythonprogram.py` or similar) then follow similar to below. For my purposes I am using a project that creates virtualenvs (via the application `pipfile` instead of manual `virtualenv` like normal but it shouldnt make a difference.)

After the spec file is generated you should open it up in an editor.
Inside the spec file in the you will see an object like so:

```
a = Analysis(
    ['spa.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
   hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
```

You should edit the `data` variable to a similar format but with your respective virtualenv python path where the public_suffix_list.dat is stored and the intended copy destination. Make sure it's a tuple and make sure the copy destination is just the destination directory.

```
datas=[('/home/newguy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Shepherd-vciLSPug/lib/python3.8/site-packages/whois/data/public_suffix_list.dat', './whois/data/')
```

Afterwards run the normal `pyinstaller pythonprogram.spec` to generate the single executable.